Chrome Extension : Navigate Second Tab based on first Tab
I have to sync up content from two website.
On the first website, I have a list of customers and their URL, I would like to read the title which contains the active customer ID, name and target.  The title is changed upon navigation in the list.
Then, navigate the second tab to a pre-decided location, which has the same customer ID at the end automatically.
I would then be able to refer to both the pages seamlessly.
Is it possible to do so using chrome extensions.
Thanks in advance.

"Is it possible to do so using chrome extensions." Yes, it's possible. If your question then becomes: "How do I do it?", then the answer will be that your question lacks not only detail and clarity, but also focus.

A) You can use content-scripts to grab the id, and then send the ID to your background.
B) Use chrome.executeScript to run code on a tab (to grab the ID).

how to send a message from content script to background:
messaging

How to use scripting from background chrome.scripting


Then in the background:
const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({url: '*://mydomain.com/*'}) // assuming only one is open, unless you have a more specific filter.
if (!tab) return;
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "https://google.com/" + id}) // update that tab to the new url


